# How to auto-increment a key of a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, max, auto-increment

I am making application in C#. In my application I am using `Dictionary` of following structure:

```
Dictionary<int, string> DataDictionary1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Here I want the key value in dictionary should be auto increment. For  that I am using logic as:

```
 string header="ABC";
 int maxKey = DataDictionary1 .Max(x => x.Key);
 DataDictionary1 .Add(maxKey + 1, header);
```

Is that a efficient way because I want to do this operation continuously. Is there any other way which is faster than this way?

Comment: Dont use max but directly access the last index (  int maxKey = DataDictionary1.Values[DataDictionary1.Length -1].Key); ) also ensure that there are items

Comment: @Polity you cannot index the values collection of a `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K, V>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why don'y you just use a `List<string>` and then add elements to it. The index of the element in the list will represent the Key. So:

```
List<string> myList = ...
```

and then:

```
string header = "ABC";
myList.Add(header);
```

Comment: Thanks  But can you tell me is it possible to access a item from list of specific index?

Comment: @Dany: Yes. `string someValue = myList[1];`

Comment: @tobias86 